# Import a ZFS pool from a disk snapshot of another machine

Tags: centos7, zfs, zfsonlinux

I have a server on Azure with a disk mounted that contains a ZFS filesystem.
I also have a snapshot of the disk (taken from Azure, not zfs snapshot) which I want to mount to a new server.

The disk created from the snapshot is visible on the new server with `lsblk`.

```
sdc      8:32   0  256G  0 disk
├─sdc1   8:33   0    8G  0 part
└─sdc2   8:34   0  248G  0 part
```

/dev/sdc2 is what I want to mount in zfs and contains the data.

Running `zpool import -a` says `no pools available to import`.

First time working with zfs so I'm not sure what to do from here. What can be done to mount the ZFS disk?

`zpool export` was not run on the original server before taking the snapshot. Is this required or can it be worked around?

Original Server OS: CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)
New Server OS: CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
Can the different OS versions be causing an issue?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. Please [take the tour](https://serverfault.com/tour) to learn how Server Fault works. Read [how to ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question. Then take a look to [the help center](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) to see if some _on-topic questions_ are already asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the LVM disk was not detected by the server.
After server restart, the disk was marked as LVM.
Running `zpool import` worked and the disk contents were accessible.